# Power Query to Select Columns from resuting table of Join Query

Tags: powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I am using power query in Power BI, I have two tables on which I have done inner join and expanded one column in the joined table.

```
let
Source = Table.NestedJoin(Sales,{"CustomerId"},Customer,{"Id"},"Customer",JoinKind.Inner),
#"Expanded Customer" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "Customer", {"Country"}, {"Customer.Country"})
in
   #"Expanded Customer"
```

This one is displaying all the columns from sales and country column from Customer table.

What I am trying to do is to display the sale ID column from sales and Country
column from Customers.

I have tried the following code but doesn't seem to work.

```
Table.SelectColumns(Source, "Customer.Country", "SaleId" )
```

I have to do this using Power query only, No DAX syntax.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Like teylyn says, you should be able to do this easily through the GUI.

The reason it isn't working is that you are referring to the first step where the `Customer.Country` column has not yet been expanded. You need to reference the `#"Expanded Customer"` step instead.

```
Table.SelectColumns(#"Expanded Customer", "Customer.Country", "SaleId")
```

Then your whole code would look like this:

```
let
    Source = Table.NestedJoin(Sales,{"CustomerId"},Customer,{"Id"},"Customer",JoinKind.Inner),
    #"Expanded Customer" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "Customer", {"Country"}, {"Customer.Country"}),
    #"Select Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Expanded Customer", "Customer.Country", "SaleId" )
in
    #"Select Columns"
```

Comment: I did some reading, turns out you cannot access the columns in a nested table/query without expanding them.

Comment: Right. That's exactly what I said.

Comment: Table.ExpandTableColumn was the key for me. if you are merging another "table" into an exisitng query, the "Source" in the example above should reference the previous step and the second parameter should reference the merged table column.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to write the code from scratch? Any objection to using the ribbon commands to achieve what you want?

Your code won't work because the `Source` item does not have the `Customer.Country` column. That is only added in the next step.

Use the ribbon to help you figure out the syntax:

As a final step in the query editor, select the unwanted columns and delete them. In Power Query, a lot of things happen in consecutive steps, not in one convoluted formula. That may make the code a bit longer, but it's easier to follow and troubleshoot.

Comment: I am trying to write it from scratch. There is no objection to using the ribbon commands but trying to learn power query and DAX.